# XSLT Copy Child nodes and turn them into Parents

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input:

```xml
<Article>
<title>Apple</title>
<number>119.057</number>
<price>90.8</price>
  <option>
    <Article>
        <title>Apple Green</title>
        <price>144.2</price>
        <number>119.086</number>
    </Article>
  </option>
</Article>
<Article>
      <title>Coconut</title>
      <number>120.882</number>
      <price>10.00</price>
</Article>
<Article>
      <title>Pinapple</title>
      <number>120.883</number>
      <price>19.00</price>
 </Article>
```

and it should look like this:

```xml
 <Article>
   <title>Apple</title>
   <number>119.057</number>
   <price>90.8</price>
 </Article>
 <Article>
   <title>Apple Green</title>
   <price>144.2</price>
   <number>119.086</number>
 </Article>
 <Article>
   <title>Coconut</title>
   <number>120.882</number>
   <price>10.00</price>
 </Article>
 <Article>
   <title>Pinapple</title>
   <number>120.883</number>
   <price>19.00</price>
 </Article>
```

My Attempt so far:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:template match="root/Article">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Article/option">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Article>
            <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
        </Article>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Identity template-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In fact i need to remove The option-Tag and the Child-Tags should become Article-Tags.
So that all nodes are on the same Level in the Tree
and finally remove the option Tag.

Thanks for your Inputs!

Comment: you are mixing up Article and Artikel everywhere, please fix

Comment: It would help to provide full XML samples that include a single root element. Your first example is missing a closing `</Article>` tag, also your XSLT references an `options` element, however your XML includes a `option` element.

Comment: Can you show a minimal but complete and well-formed XML input sample and the corresponding result you want? And are there really elements with names in different languages like `Article` and `Artikel`? Do you need to transform an `Artikel` element to an `Article`?

Comment: I just fixed the XML-codes, i also added the complete files.
Hope this helps you.
Thanks for the Support

Comment: Your input is still not well-formed XML. You must have a single root element.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: "i need to remove the `options` tag and their child tags should
become (direct chilren of) `Article` tag".

Then do just that, but with a minor correction: the tag you want to match
(and remove in the output) is `option` (not `options`).

```
<xsl:template match="Article/option">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Note the similarity to the identity template. The main difference is that
there is no `xsl:copy` tag (which would have copied the original `option` tag).

### Edit

Initially I presented only the template. Below you have the full script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="Article/option">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does generate the required output.

### Edit 2

Yet another solution. It copies only `option` content, but to keep
the proper XML formatting, I added an "envelope" root (`main`) tag.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Article">
    <!-- This matches only the root Article tag, not its grandson -->
    <main>  <!-- You need to have a main (root) tag -->
      <!-- Output only the option content -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="option"/>
    </main>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="option">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this not get output

Comment: You check this code not desire output

<Article>
   <title>A1<title>
</Article>
<Article>
   <title>A2<title>
</Article>

Comment: As I undestood your comment, you want to output **only** the content of the `option` tag. But then you will have improperly formatted XML.
Proper XML formatting requires that there is **only one** main tag (not two).

Comment: Thanks for your input so far,
But The Child Tags should become Article-Tags.
so in the end there will be no Child-Tags left.

Comment: Michael gave the right answer. My solutions given so far wera based on incomplete data and not clear description.

Answer (score 0):

Given a **well-formed** input such as:

**XML**

```
<Articles>
  <Article>
    <title>Apple</title>
    <number>119.057</number>
    <price>90.8</price>
    <option>
      <Article>
        <title>Apple Green</title>
        <price>144.2</price>
        <number>119.086</number>
      </Article>
    </option>
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <title>Coconut</title>
    <number>120.882</number>
    <price>10.00</price>
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <title>Pinapple</title>
    <number>120.883</number>
    <price>19.00</price>
  </Article>
</Articles>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Article">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::option)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="option"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="option">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will transform an `option` node from being a child of `Article` to being its sibling, returning:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Articles>
  <Article>
    <title>Apple</title>
    <number>119.057</number>
    <price>90.8</price>
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <title>Apple Green</title>
    <price>144.2</price>
    <number>119.086</number>
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <title>Coconut</title>
    <number>120.882</number>
    <price>10.00</price>
  </Article>
  <Article>
    <title>Pinapple</title>
    <number>120.883</number>
    <price>19.00</price>
  </Article>
</Articles>
```